# What does `location=$(type -p "htop")` mean in a script?

Tags: linux, shell

The script is this

```
#!/bin/bash

echo
echo "################################################################"
echo "  Installing Htop                                               "
echo "################################################################"
echo

if ! location=$(type -p "htop"); then
    sudo apt install -y htop
fi
```

I'm confused as to what this code snippet from the script does
`location=$(type -p "htop");`
I need a clear explanation about this.

Comment: There is a lot unnecessary there. `location=` just assigns the result of the *command substitution* `$(type -p "htop")` where `type -p htop` will return the absolute path to `htop` if it is found (nothing if it isn't) so upon finding no `htop`, there is an empty assignment `location=""` along with `type` returning `1` which when inverted with `!` make the `if` test `true` -- installing `htop`. Better `if ! type -p htop; then ...`

Comment: Basically `it not htop found; then install htop`.

Comment: After the `if` the variable `location` might or might not be set and you don't know why (i.e. if install fails there would be no `htop` yet)

Comment: `help type` is your friend.

Comment: BTW, note that in general, ["please explain this code" questions are too broad to be on-topic here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260466/where-should-could-someone-please-explain-this-code-to-me-questions-go).

Comment: ...the "check if a program is already installed" question linked as a duplicate is someone trying to do the same thing your sample code already does. Same thing, from a different direction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- `!` negates the exit status of the following command;
- `location=...` assigns a value to the variable `$location`;
- `$(...)` is **command substitution**. It expands to the output of the enclosed command, whose exit status is propagated as the assignment's exit status;
- `type -p htop` (double quotes are not needed here) searches for an executable `htop` in the `$PATH` and returns the full path to it. It fails if no such executable exists and there's no alias nor function named `htop` (in which case it returns an empty string, but doesn't fail).

Putting it all together, it searches for an executable named `htop`, assings the the full path to it to `$location`, and if it can't be found (and there's no alias or function defining it), it runs `sudo apt install -y htop`, which on some systems (that use `apt` to manage packages) tries to install the `htop` package with root privileges, answering `yes` to any questions.

Answer (score 1):

In short, the exit status of the assignment is the exit status of the command substitution, and the exit status of the command substitution is the exit status fo `type`.

`type -p htop` has an exit status of 0 if `htop` is a command that can be executed, with the output being the full path to the command.

The idea here is that `location` is assigned the full path to `htop` if it exists, and if it doesn't, then `sudo apt install -y htop` is run to install it. (With the slight problem, alluded to in the comments, that `location` remains if `htop` needs to be installed.)